# jQuery slider help on hiding and showing div elements

Tags: jquery, swipe, show-hide

I'm pretty rusty on jQuery and front end in general, I am trying to get a slide left effect to:

1) effectively hide a div element an image, then show a form in it's place

2) swiping right hides the form and brings back the image.

I am using basic code at the moment to get a better understanding how the hide/show works in relation to swipe left and right.

HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

jQuery code:

```
 $(function(){
    $("div.box").on("swipeleft", swipeleftHandler);
    $("div.box").on("swiperight", swiperightHandler);

    function swipeleftHandler(event){
        $(event.target).addClass("swipeleft");
        $(this).hide();
    }

    function swiperightHandler(event){
        $(event.target).addClass("swiperight");
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

This is the basic code on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/avas9eb3/

The problem I'm having is, swiping left to hide works, but swiping right to show does nothing.

And it only works once and requires a page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

After you've hidden it with the swipe left, it'll be hidden, so you couldn't capture the swipe right anyway.

Therefore, I would probably consider putting the handler on the parent element of the box that you are hooking into. Then you can find the descendant element in the handler.

```
$(function(){
    $("div.box").parent().on("swipeleft", swipeleftHandler);
    $("div.box").parent().on("swiperight", swiperightHandler);

    function swipeleftHandler(event){
        $(event.target).addClass("swipeleft");
        $(this).find("div.box").hide();
    }

    function swiperightHandler(event){
        $(event.target).addClass("swiperight");
        $(this).find("div.box").show();
    }
});
```

Note: You might need to adjust your "find" logic to be more specific if needs be depending on what siblings your box has.